# LTspice ideal diode simulation

Tags: diodes, ltspice, simulation, transient

I was trying to simulate a biased clipper circuit in LTspice, and came across this issue.

This is the schematic I used:
[image]

And the plots of voltages across V2 and R1:

[image]

Ideally, the output voltage should peak at -4V, right?
I tried the .model statement from [this answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/353827/278882), but that didn't work too.

Another strange thing that I noticed is that for greater values of load resistance, the peak slightly changes.

[image]

What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something must have gone wrong when you used the `.model` statement. Here is what I get using an ideal diode.

[image]

Which shows, as you mention, the peaks at -4V.

Comment: Value of these voltage sources?

Comment: @Sayan V1 is a sinusoid with an amplitude of 7V and frequency of 50Hz. V2 is a constant 3V voltage source.

Comment: Yes!! I forgot to rename the diode after using the statement. Also, now the voltage remains independent of the load resistance. I guess it was the diode's property that resulted in the slight change of load voltage for different resistance?

Comment: @Kruthik I think so.

Comment: @Kruthik Default diode using just `D` as the name uses [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation) with `Is = 1e-14` and `N = 1`.  [See LTspice help](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/D_Diode.htm) for more information on the parameters.

Comment: Doesn't an "ideal" diode have zero forward voltage at any current?

Comment: @Audioguru Yes, that is correct. That property is guaranteed by ```Ron=0```.

Comment: @Carl For very simple circuits like OP's it's acceptable to use `Ron=0`, but don't forget that this is a numeric simulator underneath, and zero or "infinite" values can cause numerical problems. Best avoid such cases. See my comment in the linked answer, it has the same message.